# Why AutoComplete suggestions are not updating in textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

IDE: Visual Studio, Winforms, C# .net 4.0

I am creating a textBox which is having suggestion feature. The problem is it is giving suggestions with initial letters for eg. suppose source contains 'hello user' and when user will type 'user' it won't give any suggestions,
To handle this situation I have written following code:

```
private void Type2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    source = new List<string>();
    source.Add("aaaaaa");
    source.Add("bbbbbb");
    source.Add("cccccc");
    source.Add("aa");
    source.Add("yogesshaaa");
    source.Add("yogesh aaa");

    BindTextBox(source);    
}

private void BindTextBox(List<string> bindWith)
{
    //   txt.Invalidate();
    ss = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = null;
    txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
    txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None;
    // ss.AddRange(bindWith.ToArray());

    txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ss;
    txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    ss.AddRange(bindWith.ToArray());
}

private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lstNewList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in source)
    {
        if(s.Contains(txt.Text))
        {
            lstNewList.Add(s);
        }
    }

    BindTextBox(lstNewList);
}
```

Here in `txt_TextChanged` event I am creating a newList which contains words to suggest in txtBox suggestions and I am rebinding that textBox, but it is not giving me updated suggestions.
Pls tell me how to solve this situation.

Comment: you are not adding anything to the list, you just loop through the current source and add in back. Maybe you meant if(!s.Contains(txt.Text))

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the autofill:

At first you have to call the ControlAdded event in your textbox:

```
 private void tb_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (autoText != null)
        {
            autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            addItems(DataCollection);
            autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
        }
    }
```

then creat the "addItems" method as follow:

```
 public void addItems(AutoCompleteStringCollection col)
            {
                col.Add("Value 1");
                col.Add("Value 2");
            }
```

I hope this solved your problem... have a nice day!